# Hot to fix 'VerifyVersionsTask' error at compile Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

After creating a project from scratch using `Xamarin.Form` and after updating all the libraries (nuget packages)
When compiling gives the following error:

```
Unexpected task error "VerifyVersionsTask"
```

1. Create new blank Xamarin project
2. Update to the latest nuget packages (all them)
3. Try to build the project but it failes with the following error:

> Error The “VerifyVersionsTask” task failed unexpectedly.”
>       “System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for ‘Xamarin.Android.Support.BuildTasks.NugetPackages’ threw an exception.
>   —> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already
>   been added.

Build should run without error.

Comment: It means you have a issue with your nuget packages. Could you provide your csproj, or packages.config, if you didn't enable PackageReference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [this tweet](https://twitter.com/redth/status/1166416512980344838)

> Sorry folks we have delisted 28.0.0.2 for the time being. Please revert back to 28.0.0.1 until we can resolve and release an update

You probably installed the Xamarin.Android.Support.* libraries with version 28.0.0.2 which is flawed and retracted. Revert to 28.0.0.1 for now.

Also see the related [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidSupportComponents/issues/195) for this error message and the progress.

Comment: Ok. I reverted the Xamarin.Android.Support.* to 28.0.0.1 and now the project compiles.

Comment: Great! I guess a new version will follow soon :) please accept this as an answer if it helped